# Why is the first row empty in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Could you advice please how to remove or how to avoid the first row of the **GridView** to be empty?

This is my code:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
            PopulateGridViewWithData();
    }

    void PopulateGridViewWithData()
    {

        if (Session["BookList"] == null)
        {
            List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>() { new Book() { } };
            Session["BookList"] = bookList;
        }

        gvBookRegister.DataSource = Session["BookList"];
        gvBookRegister.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when initiated:

[image]

And after inserting some data:

[image]

When initiated with an empty List:

```
List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
```

The input rows don't show up at all:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind the data source to a list.

below is an example of something I've done similar.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (!IsPostBack)  
            BindGridList();  
    } 

    protected List<Emp> GetEmpList()  
    {  
        List<Emp> lEmp = new List<Emp>();  
        Emp oemp = new Emp(1234, "Upendra", "Noida");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1234, "Upendra", "Noida");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1294, "Manish", "Noida");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1245, "Gitendra", "Delhi");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1734, "Upendra", "Noida");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1224, "Amit", "Delhi");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1204, "Jacob", "Noida");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1374, "Vishal", "Noida");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        oemp = new Emp(1934, "Rahul", "Noida");  
        lEmp.Add(oemp);  
        return lEmp;  
    }  

    protected void BindGridList()  
    {  
        GridView1.DataSource = GetEmpList();  
        GridView1.DataBind();  
    }
```

You can of course have the list be empty too .

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mathis1337 although please see my edited question.